# The loop_rate() for my node doesn't change the publish frequency

Tags: ros-melodic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm having problems with the `loop_rate()` function for my node.
I set it at 10hz and then I publish some topics in the while() loop but when I rostopic them, I see that they are published only at 4 hertz! What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
 #include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "../include/robo_base/RoboteqDevice.h"
#include "../include/robo_base/ErrorCodes.h"
#include "../include/robo_base/Constants.h"
#include "robo_explorer/robo_io.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "robo_explorer");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  std::string port = "";

  ...  

  n.getParam("/robo_explorer/port", port);
  n.getParam("/robo_explorer/sys", sys);
  n.getParam("/robo_explorer/board", riox_board);
  n.getParam("/robo_explorer/enc", enc);
  n.getParam("/robo_explorer/io", io);
  n.getParam("/robo_explorer/imu", imu);
  n.getParam("/robo_explorer/velocity", velocity);
  n.getParam("/robo_explorer/rate", rate);

  
  ros::Publisher sys_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("robo_explorer/sys", 1);
  ros::Publisher enc_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("robo_explorer/enc", 1);
  ros::Publisher vel_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("robo_explorer/velocity", 1);
  ros::Publisher io_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("robo_explorer/io", 1);
  ros::Publisher imu_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("robo_explorer/imu", 1);

  ros::Subscriber cmd_sub = n.subscribe("/robo_explorer/cmd_vel", 1, &RoboteqDevice::cmdCallback, &device);
  ros::Subscriber cmd_io = n.subscribe("/robo_explorer/io_status", 1, &RoboteqDevice::cmd_ioCallback, &device);

  double current_time =ros::Time::now().toSec();
  double last_time =ros::Time::now().toSec();

  
  ros::Rate loop_rate(rate);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
 
   
    //System Topic
    if (sys == 1){
    .....
  sys_pub.publish(msg_sys);

  }


    //Encoder Topic
    if (enc == 1){
vel_pub.publish(msg_vel);
enc_pub.publish(msg_enc);
...
    }


   //IO Topic
   if (io == 1){
     ...
io_pub.publish(msg_io);
    }

   if (imu == 1){
..
imu_pub.publish(msg_imu);
      
    }

    ros::spinOnce();

    loop_rate.sleep();
    ++count;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

These are all the published topics:

```
/robo_explorer/cmd_vel
/robo_explorer/enc
/robo_explorer/imu
/robo_explorer/io
/robo_explorer/io_status
/robo_explorer/sys
/robo_explorer/velocity
```

and for example this is one of the output:

rostopic echo /robo_explorer/io

```
data: "1612553682.755857579,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100"
---
data: "1612553683.020352972,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101"
---
data: "1612553683.285076521,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,102"
---
data: "1612553683.551031712,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,103"
---
data: "1612553683.816192936,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104"
---
data: "1612553684.082027678,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,105"
---
data: "1612553684.347815952,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,106"
---
data: "1612553684.613140284,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,107"
---
data: "1612553684.878549824,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,108"
---
data: "1612553685.144171685,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,109"
```

as you can see, there are only 4 samples for each second.
How can I solve this?

P.S. this is the output for the hz:

```
rostopic hz /robo_explorer/io
subscribed to [/robo_explorer/io]
average rate: 3.773
    min: 0.265s max: 0.265s std dev: 0.00007s window: 3
average rate: 3.771
    min: 0.265s max: 0.265s std dev: 0.00022s window: 7
average rate: 3.771
    min: 0.265s max: 0.266s std dev: 0.00022s window: 11
average rate: 3.770
    min: 0.265s max: 0.266s std dev: 0.00031s window: 15
average rate: 3.768
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371179/the-loop_rate()-for-my-node-doesn%27t-change-the-publish-frequency/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2021-02-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2021-02-05**:
I found out that probably the issue is related to the sensor reading. The cpu requires some additional time to read from each sensor and so the node cannot respects the frequency.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-02-05**:
How do you set the frequency, and have you confirmed that the value is correct after setting it?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2021-02-05**:
I get the parameter from the launch file and it is correctly received since I can print it in the main(). Moreover, I tried to directly write, i.e, loop_rate(20) and it still runs at 4 hz. However, I'm pretty sure it is the payload that slows down the whole process, unfortunately.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-02-05**:
Ah, then yes, I have to agree :/

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-02-06**:
You may want to experiment by changing the setting to less than 4Hz, say 2Hz. If the maximum speed is 4Hz because of the sensor reading time, then it should work correctly at 2Hz.
Alternatively, you can check if the speed is still 4Hz without running `loop_rate.sleep();`.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2021-02-06**:
If I decrease the frequency, i.e., 2 Hz, it goes to 2 Hz, so unfortunately, it's the acquisition time that lowers the overall frequency. If I shuts down some topics, the frequency agrees with the setting, so I can assume that the loop_rate() is working fine. Thank you for your help, guys!

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-02-06**:
It is a good idea to describe the answer and pretend that it has been resolved for those who will follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out that the loop_rate() function is working fine, the problem is related to the acquisition time needed by the functions to retrieve the data from the sensors.
By skipping some of the functions used to acquire some data, the node runs at the correct rate.

---

Originally posted by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) with karma: 287 on 2021-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2